# Tailwind CSS top and bottom border not working

Tags: css, tailwind-css, border

I'm trying to place a border top and bottom only (not right or left).

From what I can see there are no conflicting css tags

If I use the following it displays nothing:

className="border-y-2 border-gray-3 h-24 ml-4 mb-0 w-full"

If I use this, it displays a border on all sides...

className="border-solid border-y-2 border-gray-3 h-24 ml-4 mb-0 w-full"

Am I missing something on the tailwind docs?
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width#customizing-your-theme

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]  here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a little modification:

```html
className="border-t border-b border-gray-300 h-24 ml-4 mb-0 w-full"
```

Here,
In this modified className:

- border-t adds a border to the top of the element.
- border-b adds a border to the bottom of the element.
- border-gray-300 specifies the color of the border.

This will apply borders only to the top and bottom of the element, leaving the left and right sides border less.
Hope this will help!

Comment: Hi Rashmi,
Thanks for this, tried that but still no luck. "border-gray-3" is a color I declare in my custom.scss file like so:

$primary: #d23600;
$secondary: #150604;
$success: #39a14c;
$white: #ffffff;
$black-1: #1b1a1a;
$green-1: #39a14c;
$red-1: #e30612;
$gray-1: #c4c1c0;
$gray-2: #e8e7e7;
$gray-3: #c4c4c4;
$gray-4: #717070;

Comment: Hi Tom, please check the tailwind configuration, make sure you have added 
@tailwind base;
in your style.scss file. Then restart the server and check. If it still won't work LMK!

Answer (score 0):

The most common mistake is forgetting to add `@tailwind base` .
Inside that, it applies `border-style: solid` to all elements as well as a default `border-color`.

Moreover, `border-gray-3` is not a default color for tailwind. Maybe you meant `border-gray-300` ?

Lastly, `border-y` was introduced in version 3, are you sure you're not using version 1 or 2 ?

Comment: You were right, it was the @tailwind base.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-t-2` for top and `border-b-2` for bottom. You can use arbitrary values as well `border-t-[3px]`.
Example using your snippet :

```
className="border-solid border-t-2 border-b-2 border-gray-3 h-24 ml-4 mb-0 w-full"
```

Answer (score 0):

### first className miss border-style

it doesn't appear because border property need three values

- border-width
- border-style
- border-color

we write it in css `border: 1px solid black;`

### the color gray-3 is not default color in tailwind

check: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#default-color-palette

example how to write it in tailwind:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="border-solid border-y-2 border-gray-300 h-24 ml-4 mb-0 mt-4 w-full">
  hello world
</div>
```